# Python - using API to get a responses title

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to modify some existing code to return the value from 'title' from an API call. Was wondering if its possible?

Example API Url: http://domain.com/rest/getSong.view?u=username&p=password&v=1.8.0&id=11452

The above URL returns:

```
<domain-response xmlns="http://domain.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0">
<song id="11452" parent="11044" title="The Title" album="The Album"/>
</domain-response>
```

Now is there a way to use python to get the 'title' value if I know the id?

Example of current code using the REST API in a file called domain.py

```
def get_playlist(self, playlist_id):
    Addon.log('get_playlist: ' + playlist_id)
    payload = self.__get_json('getPlaylist.view', {'id': playlist_id})
    if payload:
        songs = self.listify(payload['playlist']['entry'])
        self.display_music_directory(songs)
```

Rest of referenced code from another file called default.py

```
elif Addon.plugin_queries['mode'] == 'playlist': 
    subsonic.get_playlist(Addon.plugin_queries['playlist_id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As your response is in XML format, the intuitive way to use an XML parser. Here's how to use `lxml` to parse your response and get the title of song with ID 11452:

```
from lxml import etree

s = """<domain-response xmlns="http://domain.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0">
<song id="11452" parent="11044" title="The Title" album="The Album"/>
</domain-response>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(s)
song = tree.xpath("//ns:song[@id=\'11452\']",namespaces={'ns':'http://domain.org/restapi'})
print song[0].get('title')
```

It's worth mentioning that there's also a dirty way to get the title if you don't care about the rest content by using regular expression:

```
import re
print re.compile("song id=\"11452\".*?title=\"(.*?)\"").search(s).group(1)
```

Comment: regex isn't likely to work even in this simple case since there's no guarantee, that `id` comes before `title`.

Comment: @bereal: yes, that's why I said it's a dirty way. I personally use those kinds of scripts for my quick tasks, just run once and never use them back.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the song id will not always bee 11452, it will always change, so is there a way to ignor the song id and just get the title?

Comment: Then just don't put the id in the xpath: `song = tree.xpath("//ns:song",namespaces={'ns':'http://domain.org/restapi'})`